# Blender 2.7 render view badly pixelated but all other views are good/fine/ok

Tags: rendering, uv

I am brand new to Blender. I have tried all remedies offered, adjusting resolution, dimensions, etc... but I could get none of them to address the problem:

Render views are very badly pixelated looking, as divided along edges in this cylinder.

[image]

But, in Material or Texture view, image quality looks excellent.

[image]

Perhaps in my learning curve I had adjusted some obscure parameter which permanently causes this.

If I paste the object into a startup Blender Render, the problem persists.  But, it looks fantastic in other non-render views.  It's a head-scratcher.

Sorry for the repeat, but no remedies worked.

Comment: First thing to do is to upload a copy of your file to [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), and edit the link to the file into your question. That way, those who want to help have more information, and have less need to guess at the answer. One thing that would cause the phenomenon you observe is if you have a subsurf modifier assigned to the walls, and adjusted the "view" parameter under "Subdivisions", (in the lower left of the modifier panel) but failed to adjust the "Render" parameter just below it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry - Blender's working just fine :)

The Render View algorithm is set at a low quality value for performance reasons, so you can manipulate the view of the model in real time with approximate ray-trace lighting conditions including reflections, transmissions, transparency, etc. It's not meant to give you an excellent result, just a guide result. If you want an excellent result, F12 :)

Material view only takes into account diffusion and light - no reflections, transmissions - so it's even quicker to calculate. There are no calculations done to approximate reflections or caustics, which is what's 'fogging up' your Render View.

Blender Render (otherwise known as 'Blender Internal' or 'BI') is supported, but no longer developed. Everyone's moving to the Cycles render engine (or other third party alternatives). Among many other features Cycles includes flexibility in setting both Preview and Final render settings independently. This means you can increase your Render View quality quite a bit... at the expense of view-handling performance.

As an aside... for a tiled pattern that's one helluva huge bmp you're using :) Think about using a smaller tile that just captures one iteration of the pattern: then in the **Texture > Image Mapping** panel, set it to Repeat and increase the X and Y values until you're happy.